# How do I get a desktop notification from a web app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, notifications, desktop-application

I need to create a web app for a client, and one of the requirements is whenever an event is triggered there should be some desktop notification in Windows XP/7 that tells them of the event. Similar to the balloon that pops-up when a new file is added to a folder in Dropbox.

I am using Rails for the web app, but have never done any desktop development. What should I be looking at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this: [Growl Notifications from a Web Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109786/growl-notifications-from-a-web-server)

plus Growl for windows meet your needs? http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/developers.aspx

Comment: This looks like the solution I need. Thanks!

Comment: Any chance to create Desktop Notifications on other OSs(like Linux, Mac etc..)From ASP.NET Web Applications.?

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth looking at [Noti](http://notiapp.com).

This tool allows web apps to push notifications to a small app running on `OS X`, `Windows` and `Linux`.

Answer (score -1):

Would RSS-enabling the application, coupled with a RSS widget on the desktop, suffice? This has a few drawbacks - for example, it requires setup on the workstations and is not immediate. But it is non-proprietary.

If this is a Windows environment, perhaps the application could use the Windows command [msg.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ts_cmd_msg.mspx?mfr=true) to pop up an alert box (assuming Windows messenger service is enabled on the workstations).

Comment: That may be possible, but that seems a little cludgy, no? You mean like have the user install say Google RSS Reader, and then just import an RSS feed from the web app? If that's the case, when a new notification comes, will the RSS reader interrupt the user (if they are inside another program for instance) or will it just increment in the background? I need them to be interrupted immediately, without it being an annoying interruption.

Comment: Yes, and it won't be immediate, but it's non-proprietary. If this is a Windows environment, maybe your application could use "net send"?

Comment: Can you give me more details on 'net send'? Like a link to some docs or something?

Comment: [net send (link)](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_send.mspx?mfr=true) is a Microsoft Windows command. It will pop up an alert box on the user's window.

Comment: Actually, google msg.exe. It seems to have replaced the net send functionality (and has several useful options).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Telegram](https://desktop.telegram.org/) (desktop portable version included) with [TeleNotify](https://github.com/ppati000/tele_notify) gem. Downside is, your app must have HTTPS. But with [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) you can get your app working with SSL for free, even without changing your source code.